# SR Latch internal conflicts

Tags: digital-logic, signal, logic-gates, latch, logic-level

it is known that "11" are invalid inputs for a SR Latch. But I do not understand the reason of that. I cannot see the electrical conflict in this structure:

[image]

If R = 1, its NOR gate will give 0, for any value of the other input signal. 
If S = 1, its NOR gate will give 0, for any value of the other input signal.

So we will get 0 at both output. What is the problem? I may understand that maybe it is not practical useful, but I do not see any conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conflict. There is nothing wrong with "11" as input to this circuit.

The ONLY problem is that if both inputs change from "1" to "0" **simultaneously** (whatever that means!), you can't predict the final state of the outputs.

If one changes before the other, then there's still no problem.

Comment: precisely, what will happen if they change from 1 to 0 simultaneously? Q and /Q would oscillate?

Comment: No, they won't oscillate, but they could end up in a metastable state for an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: But which is the cause? If S and R go from 1 to 0, I'd say Q and /Q will be 0. This will mean that immediately both the NOR gates will give 1 for both Q and /Q. So both NOR will have 0 and 1 as inputs, so they will give 0. So they will have 00 as inputs, so they will 1. Is it not correct?

Comment: No. Gates don't function in discrete time steps like that. Time is fundamentally continuous -- and so are signals.

Answer (score 1):

There is no electrical conflict. It is a well defined state, but the conflict is only with the expected logic output because Q will not be /Q as both Q and/Q are 0.

Comment: But which is the problem? Q and /Q are output signals, they are not complementary "given" signal. There is not any imposition on the fact that they must be complementary. I would say simply: in a SR Latch, the output signals are always complementary, except for 11 inputs

Comment: @Kinka-Byo There **is** an assumption that Q and /Q are complementary, and any logic that uses the output of the latch depends on that assumption. It **does** matter. Also, if you transition directly from this illegal input condition to the hold condition then the state of the latch will be indeterminate.